# Programs with Boost Dependency Fail to Compile in Qt Creator

Tags: boost, mingw, qt-creator

I get undefined reference errors to various things in the `boost::` namespace  if I attempt to compile programs that use any parts of Boost Libraries in Qt Creator 2.5.2. At first I thought it's because I was mixing static Boost libraries with shared Qt libraries, so I recompiled Boost with `link=shared runtime-link=shared` build option, but the problem remains. I then started a Non-Qt, Plain C++ project that consists of nothing more than a main.cpp containing a slightly modified Boost test program:

```
// main.cpp, cin-less version of 
//     http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#test-your-program

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main() {

    std::string headerLines = "To: George Shmidlap\n" \
                              "From: Rita Marlowe\n" \
                              "Subject: Will Success Spoil Rock Hunter?\n" \
                              "---\n" \
                              "See subject.\n";

    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );
    boost::smatch matches;

    std::string::iterator newLinePos = std::find(headerLines.begin(), headerLines.end(), '\n');
    std::string::iterator startPos = headerLines.begin();

    while(newLinePos != headerLines.end()) {
        if (boost::regex_match(std::string(startPos, newLinePos++), matches, pat)) {
            std::cout << "\nRegex Match: " << matches[2];
        }

        startPos = newLinePos;
        newLinePos = std::find(startPos, headerLines.end(), '\n');
    }

    char temp[3];
    std::cin.getline(temp, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

Debug {
    LIBS += -lboost_regex-mgw46-mt-d-1_51
}

release {
    LIBS += -lboost_regex-mgw46-mt-1_51
}
```

Compiling the above project from within Qt Creator, or using mingw32-make in command line, gives:

```
E:\BoostTest-483-MinGW_Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function `ZN5boost13match_resultsIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEE17raise_logic_errorEv':

c:\tdm-mingw32\include\boost\regex\v4\match_results.hpp:562: error: undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)'

E:\BoostTest-483-MinGW_Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function `ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE14construct_initERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE':

c:\tdm-mingw32\include\boost\regex\v4\perl_matcher_common.hpp:55: error: undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)'

[etc...]
```

Compiling main.cpp from command line, without Qt Creator or mingw32-make, works just fine:

```
E:\BoostTest>g++ -s -O3 main.cpp -o main.exe -lboost_regex-mgw46-mt-1_51

E:\BoostTest>main.exe

Regex Match: Will Success Spoil Rock Hunter?

E:\BoostTest>g++ -s -O3 main.cpp -o main-dbg.exe -lboost_regex-mgw46-mt-d-1_51

E:\BoostTest>main-dbg.exe

Regex Match: Will Success Spoil Rock Hunter?
```

Tested with:

- TDM-MinGW32 (MinGW 4.6.1)
- My own builds of MinGW:

  - MinGW 4.6.3 with dwarf2 exceptions handling
  - MinGW 4.6.3 with SJLJ exceptions handling
- Boost Libraries 1.51.0 (built from source with each of the above compiler builds, static and shared libraries)
- Qt Framework 4.8.3 for MinGW, precompiled binaries.
- Qt Creator 2.5.2 for Windows.

I've checked Qmake's makescpecs configuration files, among other things, but still cannot figure out the root of the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely far too late to help you, but I've just had to figure this one out today. I too am using mingw32 and Qt and had the same undefined reference.

I first resolved it by adding the following in `some file', based on another StackOverflow question:

```
namespace boost
{
    void throw_exception(std::exception const &e) { assert(false); }
}
```

However I actually wanted to throw an exception, so changed the `assert(false);` to a `throw e;`. That immediately threw up the compile error:

```
error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

...which gives a clue.

The trick turned out to be adding `CONFIG += exceptions` (along with `console` so cout/printf etc. actually do anything, that was a real pain!) to my qmake file. I have no idea what is really going on here, maybe most Linux distros add something special to the qmake spec files or whatever.